# Discord selfbot erros

Tags: python, discord

I am making a discord self bot that utilizes the "selfcord" library in python so when i send "$smile" it sends the smile emoji, i know i could just type ":smile" but this is the start i need to continue to develop it.

```
import discord
import selfcord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.self_messages = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", self_bot=True, intents=intents)
selfcord.login("MY TOKEN")

@bot.command(name="troll")
async def troll(ctx):
    await ctx.send("")

bot.run("MY TOKEN", bot=False)
```

Tried this so far and i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Desktop\Emojis\bot.py", line 6, in <module>
    intents.self_messages = True
AttributeError: 'Intents' object has no attribute 'self_messages'
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that selfbots are against the ToS oif Discord and therefore you will probably not get any help here.

Comment: Already fixed the issue found a good base online and got the script working